# Abbreviating and expanding IP v6 addresses with APL

Tags: ip-address, apl

Recently I solved [a challenge](https://www.dyalog.com/uploads/files/student_competition/2019_problems_phase2.pdf#page=13) (problem 1 of the 3rd easy problem set of phase 2 of the '19 APL Competition) on abbreviating and expanding IP v6 addresses. For that matter, I had to write two functions, `AbbreviateIPv6` and `ExpandIPv6`. The first function ought to take a character vector of a v6 IP address and abbreviate it like [this online tool](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6Compress). The second function ought to undo exactly what the first one did.

I need a community review because these two were among a series of problems rated as easy and while most of them were fairly easy to solve and could be decently solved in a couple of lines, I found really hard to write the `AbbreviateIPv6` function so I think I overlooked something. What is more, I failed to find a solution that didn't use regular expressions, which bothered me even more.

First, a helper function:

```
:Namespace ReplaceFirst
    _ReplaceFirst_ ← {
        ⍝ Operator that replaces the first occurrence of the left operand with the right operand.
        ⍝ e.g. ('ui' ReplaceFirst 'fafa') 'this ui is ui' gives 'this fafa is ui'

        startAt ← ⊃⍸⍺⍺⍷⍵
        stopAt ← startAt + (¯1+≢⍺⍺)×startAt>0
        pruned ← ⍵/⍨ ~(startAt∘<∧≤∘stopAt)⍳≢⍵
        replaceAt ← (>∘0⍴⊢) startAt
        ∊ ((⊂,⍵⍵)@replaceAt) pruned
    }
:EndNamespace
```

that I used in the `AbbreviateIPv6` function:

```
AbbreviateIPv6 ← {
  ⍝ Monadic function taking character vector as input and returning character vector.
  ⍝ Abbreviates an IP v6 address.
  ⍝ e.g. '2001:0DB8:0000:0042:0000:8A2E:0370:7334' becomes '2001:DB8:0:42:0:8A2E:370:7334'
  ReplFirst←⎕fix 'file://path/to/ReplaceFirst.dyalog'

  reduced ← ('0000' ':0{1,3}' ⎕R (,¨'0' ':'))⍵
  runs ← ⌽ ⍴∘'0:'¨ 1+2×⍳7
  shortened ← {(⍵ ReplFirst._ReplaceFirst_ '') reduced}¨ runs
  ((⊃∘⍋≢¨)⊃⊢) shortened
}
```

I know I could've defined the `_ReplaceFirst_` as a function inside `AbbreviateIPv6` specialized for the case I wanted, but I figured the function was getting so long I might as well write a general operator that I might reuse later.

Finally, just for comparison, I was able to write the `ExpandIPv6` in a much more compact way:

```
ExpandIPv6 ← {
    ⍝ Monadic function expecting and returning character vector.
    ⍝ Expands an abbreviated IP v6 address.
    ⍝ e.g. '2041:0:140F::875B:131B' gives '2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B'.

    colons ← +/':'=⍵
    intermediate ← ('::' ⎕R(':0'⍴⍨ 3+2×7-colons))⍵
    splits ← (':'∘≠⊆⊢) intermediate
    LeftZeroPadder ← (⍴∘'0')∘(4∘-)∘≢,⊢
    ⊃ {∊⍺':'⍵}/ LeftZeroPadder¨ splits
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could link directly to the specific problem instead of the general page?

Comment: @Adám I can link to the year but I can only find the problem in a pdf, not in a specific URL.

Comment: You can link to the right page though.

Comment: @Adám done! I linked to the challenge page where you can test phase 1 submissions and included a descriptive path to the problem at hand

Comment: I meant [link straight to the right page in the pdf](https://www.dyalog.com/uploads/files/student_competition/2019_problems_phase2.pdf#page=13).

Comment: @Adám I had no idea that was possible; updated the link and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using regular expressions is a perfectly sensible approach. What you're missing is probably that Dyalog APL allows setting a Match Limit with `⍠'ML' n` where a positive `n` limits to the first `n` matches and a negative `n` limits to *the* (absolute value of) nth match. With this in mind, I'd use regular expressions extensively:

```
AbbreviateIPv6 ← {
    collapsed0s ← '\b0{1,3}' ⎕R '' ⊢ ⍵      ⍝ remove up to 3 leading 0s
    runsOf0s ← '\b(0:)*0\b'                 ⍝ 0:0:0:…:0
    nth ← - ⊃⍒ runsOf0s ⎕S 1 ⊢ collapsed0s  ⍝ 1: lengths, ⊃⍒: index of first max
    abbreviated ← runsOf0s ⎕R ':' ⍠'ML' nth ⊢ collapsed0s
    ':::' '^:$' ⎕R '::' ⊢ abbreviated       ⍝ exactly two
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFPS8MwFL/3U7yDEJUNUgse3s2joCh6HUK6pl0ha0qT1Y4xEAQPQocIOwriwW/gF8oXmWmmrpuMsV8gIeH9/rwXlotuNGZCJovFWRgWvEyZ5ufX5SmYpxeYeGDRl0KwXPGIKvdKeiGd@J1gSsDM5jdA7Pn8Aab@AgdTv0HBh7LkMMpBSwhAcBalWQJUOcVilKmreCV3SPHomPZCAptotCg2yzx8InXsTA8csWttH0392pKbzW/Bd2naoZ2KjzZFluiB6vzwENIs4hXIGOK0UBqGrHIG7G8SkTNq69t20fZbv5PLC7KMsu7mFAiirSJ3ePA7o@beVLa1Vy3yivW1GIO@l97031cQaoG7N@LtIJ5YIA2CYD@ivx/R30ZsbVscl@Ubna3ZEu8b)

Notes:

- [The linked](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6Compress) online IPv6 compressor gives wrong results, as do many others. [This one](https://dnschecker.org/ipv6-compress.php) seems to work, even though it misses the occasional shortening opportunity. I still have not found an online tool that compresses both fully *and* correctly.
- If `runsOf0s ⎕S 1` doesn't find any runs of 0s, it returns `⍬` so `nth` becomes `0`, which is fine even though `'ML' 0` means "no limit" because there are no matches.

Comment: Lovely, thanks! The ⍠'ML' and the negative argument to it were exactly what I was missing... Also, `\b` in the regex also matches the beginning of the string, right? Finally, I don't understand if the "edge cases" you mention correspond to maximal compression when the whole IP address is just 0s.

Comment: @RGS Yes, `\b` matches any word **b**oundary, even at the edges of a string. The comment was imprecise: Since we substitute `0:0` with `:` we end up with `:::` when counting the surrounding colons (except at beginning or end where we get two, and for all-zero where we get one).